# Page Context in Background Utility Item

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I created a Background Utility Item component that uses the empApi component to listen on capture data changes. I need it to be aware of the Page Context and able to get the record id of the current page.
I tried to use the `force:hasRecordId` interface with `component.get("v.recordId")` but it doesn't work. If I remove the `lightning:backgroundUtilityItem` interface and use it in Utility Bar, I am able to retrieve the record id.
Do you know if it is by design or an issue in Salesforce? Do you have any workaround?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:backgroundUtilityItem,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" required="true" default="/data/ChangeEvents" />
<aura:attribute name="checkRecordId" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:attribute name="debug" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:handler name="SubscribeStreamingChannelEvent" event="c:SubscribeStreamingChannelEvent" action="{!c.handleSubscribeEvent}"/>
<aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.unsubscribe}"/>
<c:StreamingChannelSubscriber channel="{!v.channel}" debug="{!v.debug}" />
```

```
({
    handleSubscribeEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        const debug = component.get("v.debug");
        const message = event.getParam('recordData');
        const eventType = message.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType;
        const entityName = message.payload.ChangeEventHeader.entityName;
        const userId = message.payload.ChangeEventHeader.commitUser.substring(0, 15); //15 digit id of transaction commit user
        const signedInUser= $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id").substring(0, 15); //15 digit id of logged in user
        const checkRecordId = component.get("v.checkRecordId");
        /**
         * Conditions:
         * - Change Type should not be create
         * - Record Id must present in modified recordIds
         * - User who modified the record should not be logged in user
         * */
        if(!(eventType === "CREATE")){
            //Condition 1 - Change type is not "created"
            Array.from(message.payload.ChangeEventHeader.recordIds).forEach( recordId => {
                if(debug && checkRecordId) console.log("Record Id on page = " + component.get("v.recordId") + " - Record Id in event = " + recordId);
                if(!checkRecordId || (checkRecordId && recordId === component.get("v.recordId"))){
                    //Condition 2 - Record Id match found &&
                    //Condition 3 - commit user is not logged in user
                    //Display console log with changed values
                    if(debug) console.log(`${eventType} event captured on ${entityName} by user id ${userId}`);
                    if(debug) console.log("Values changed are:");
                }
             });
        }
    }
})
```